# Как сделать однонаправленную связь OneToMany, имея составной первичный ключ?

Tags: java, jpa

Есть две сущности:

**TableA**:

```
public class TableA implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String someParams;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableA", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TableB> tableB = new ArrayList<>();

public TableA() {}

public long getId() {...}
public void setId(long id) {...}
public String getSomeParams() {...}
public void setSomeParams(String someParams) {...}
public List<TableB> getTableB() {...}
public void setTableB(List<TableB> tableB)
...
}
```

И **TableB** с составным первичным ключом, один из которых является ещё и внешним ключом к TableA:

```
@Embeddable
public class TableBPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "tableA", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long tableA;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 62)
    @Column(name = "param", nullable = false, length = 62, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String param;

public TableBPK () {}
public TableBPK (long tableA, String param) {...}

public String getParam() {...}
public void setParam(String param) {...}    
public long getTableA() {...}
public void setTableA(long tableA) {...}
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected TableBPK tableBPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 62)
    @Column(name = "param", nullable = false, length = 62, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private String param;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 510)
    @Column(length = 510)
    private String value;
    @JoinColumn(name = "tableA", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private TableA tableA;

public TableB() {}

public TableB(String param, String value, TableA tableA) {
    this.tableBPK = new tableBPK(tableA.getId(), param);
    this.param = param;
    this.value = value;
    this.tableA = tableA;
}

public String getParam() {...}
public void setParam(String param) {...}
public String getValue() {...}
public void setValue(String value) {...}
public TableA getTableA() {...}
public void setTableA(TableA tableA) {...}
public TableBPK getTableBPK() {...}
public void setTableBPK(TableBPK tableBPK) {...}
...
}
```

Двунаправленную связь я реализовал без проблем, а вот сделать однонаправленную, чтобы только **TableA** знал о **TableB** у меня не получается, подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Имеется в виду, что я пытаюсь убрать связь с **TableA** в **TableB**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected TableBPK tableBPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 62)
    @Column(name = "param", nullable = false, length = 62, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private String param;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 510)
    @Column(length = 510)
    private String value;

public TableB() {}

public TableB(String param, String value, TableA tableA) {
    this.tableBPK = new tableBPK(tableA.getId(), param);
    this.param = param;
    this.value = value;
}
...
}
```

В **TableA** меняю

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableA", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TableB> tableB = new ArrayList<>();
```

на

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "tableA", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<TableB> tableB = new ArrayList<>();
```

И получаю следующее исключение:

```
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-46] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [table_b.tableA].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(ru.test.entities.TableB --> [DatabaseTable(table_b)])
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Видимо я не правильно выполняю @JoinColumn в **TableA**, но как надо сделать - не понимаю

Comment: Напишите более подробно что именно не получается, приведите примеры кода, где можно посмотреть проблему.

Comment: Обновил, надеюсь теперь понятно описал)

Answer (score 0):

У вас уже реализовано: в TableA ->

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableA", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<TableB> tableB = new ArrayList<>();
```

в TableB <-

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private TableA tableA;
```

только привяжите к конкретному полю класса, типа Id или любому другому, которое вам нужно. В вашем случае это некое поле TableA tableA в сущности TableВ которое должно существовать в БД.